# Set home in any world Starbound

Tags: starbound

I know, that in Starbound you can set a "Home Planet", so when you go with the spaceship, you can always return to your home planet easyly.

But my question is about when you are in the planet.

Supose, whe you warp from the spaceship to the planet, you "land" on the coordinate X = 0.

then, you move, for example, to X = (+/-)1000. And you build a House, with your bed, and different stuff. Ok, you warp, to the Ship, and you come back, but you spawn again in X = 0.

So, the now that the "scenario" is explained, the question:

Exist any form to set you house as "warp point" when you come from the spaceship?